# Change maxLength dynamically in textarea ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I want to change maxLength for textarea dynamically.
I tried this:

```
{
        xtype: 'textareafield',

        msgTarget: 'under',
        fieldLabel: __('text_sms'),            
        maxLength: 60,
        name: 'text-sms',
        bind: {
            value: __('sms_text_template'),
            afterSubTpl: '<span>{length}/{maxLength}</span>'
        },

        listeners: {
            change: function (el) {
                el.setMaxLength(60); // error is not a function
            }
        }

}
```

And also I tried to bind value maxLength:

```
 bind: {
            value: __('sms_text_template'),
            maxLength: '{maxLength}'
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define getter and setter to textarea and after this you're free to call them: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lcp)

**EDIT:**
This is how you do it with binding: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lcq)
[maxLength](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html#cfg-maxLength) isn't bindable, so to make it, you need getter & setter and after this you can change them from viewmodel.